# jQuery data sent from PHP is not the correct format?

Tags: php, jquery, pdo

I am using jQuery to send a part number from one php file to another.
The part number is received correctly in the destination php file, but when when I try to use it, it does not work.

Here is the strange thing: To test,when I use $mpn=STA-12 (or any other value that exists in table2), in destination php file, the connection is established and the relevant data is extracted, BUT when THE SAME DATA is fetched, it does not work

Here is the destination PHP file:

```
<?php

$row['mpn'] = $_GET['q'];


include("order/connection.php");    



echo "mpn is here : ".$row['mpn']; // It displays STA-12 but doesn't data get fetched!

$mpn=$row['mpn'];


//$mpn="STA-12"; // *** When I actually put this line in, it all works ***

$stmt = $pd->prepare("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE part_number =  :part_number " );

//$stmt->execute(array());

$stmt->execute(array(':part_number' => $mpn));

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
 //... rest of the code
 ?>
```

This jQuery script copied from W3:

```
<script>
function showUser(str) {
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML =    this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","serv.reply3.3.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}
```

And this is where it is called from:

```
<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Choose</option>
<option value=" <?php echo $row["mpn"]; ?> ">items</option>

</select>
</form>
```

Comment: `table2 =:part_number`? How can table equals a value?

Comment: It is very likely you get an sql error, try a `print_r($stmt)` or turn on the PDO exceptions.

Comment: `ON table2 = mcart.mpn` is a wrong join too

Comment: First you need to search out a simple SQL tutorial. SO is not a tutorial site!

Comment: Added print_r statement and it returns:

Comment: Whenever you want to compare two (or more) values you have to specify the columns within the tables you want, not only the table itself. How should your DB know which column to use to compare?

Comment: _Added print_r statement and it returns_ WHAT???

Comment: @jack what is the return value? Is it `false`, `null`, the actual value? You have to put the value in there!

Comment: with print_r($stmt) it returns:Object ( [queryString] => SELECT * FROM table2 LEFT JOIN mcart ON table2.part_number = mcart.mpn WHERE table2.part_number =:part_number )

Comment: The actual value is STA-12, as in the example i have put.When I write the value in the file it works but when when it is fetched , it doesn't work.

Comment: Hey, that means you have given us not the code you are actually using. You should use the correct code, just do a copy&paste and don't modify anything (except somthing like passwords etc.).

Comment: Can you please have another look as I have simplified the question quite a lot. It just seems an impossible case!

Comment: The only thing I can come up is that the line $row['mpn'] = $_GET['q']; might be getting a string and not a variable!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is finally solved.
Since the code was copied from another example, the jQuery variable sent over, contained some EXTRA information that when ECHO'ed didn't show.

echo "mpn is here : ".$row['mpn']; that displayed STA-12, actually contained ' string(6) " STA-12" ', which was discovered by doing:
 var_dump( $row['mpn']).
This had my head scratching for days.